# Building MobileVLCKit from git.videolan.org repository on macOsX with XCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcodebuild, vlc, libvlc

I would like to make an application for iOS(iPhone and iPad) that can play streaming videos through RTSP protocol (that includes mms). I imagined to achive a specified application using VLC player or libVLC library.

On the official vlc git repository (http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=tree) in **projects/macosx/framework/** folder there is xcode project **MobileVLCKit.xcodeproj** for which I assume that is a somewhat usable VLC framework for iOS.

Now the problem is that I can't/don't know how to build this project. When I try to build MobileVLCKit.xcodeproj I get an error that says it can't find files inside extras/contrib/hosts/i686-apple-darwin10/ios/ folder.

I have looked within that folder (extras/contrib) and managed to create folder (with files) extras/contrib/hosts/i686-apple-darwin10/ with make, but there is no ios folder.

So, does anybody knows how to successfully build MobileVLCKit?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ git clone git://git.videolan.org/MobileVLC.git
$ cd MobileVLC
$ ./buildMobileVLC.sh
```

See:
http://wiki.videolan.org/MobileVLC

Note, using any portion of VLC in your app, makes your app open source and GPL.

Answer (score 0):

i am fighting to build this ios version.

if you git clone the today the version, ,you'ld find a more complete with ios support into the extra folder : extra/contrib/src/Distributions/ios.mak and extra/package/ios/build_for_iOS.sh

extra/contrib/bootstrap is now "ios" compliant !

be aware this version need ios4.2 (see build_for_iOS.sh)

i have problems with ffmpeg but it's another story

vlc build for ios need  a "howto" !!!

the entry point is  "build_for_iOS.sh" build_for_iOS.sh calls bootstrap

when this is done correctly (good luck), MobileVLCKit will find the files it needs (i hope)

Comment: with some fixes i achived to compile (not run !)  in arm7 using ios4.1

Comment: it's run (MobileVLC 1.0) with MobileVLCKit from actual trunk

Answer (score 0):

Don't use git to get the most recently source code。
Since vlc is not available for iOS。
but you can get mobilevlc 1.1.0, from videolan.com

http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ios.html

and you 'd better install Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2